# Displaying multiple JPanels from different methods on a single JFrame

Tags: java, user-interface, methods, jframe, jpanel

I have a main JFrame (screen) and separate JPanels all contained by their own method. The main method calls another method (create) which hosts the JFrame and latter adds all other JPanels to it. My problem is that only 1 of those JPanels is displayed, it changes every time I run the code. I've tried having 1 main JPanel and the methods add their components (JLables...) to it but I get the same problem. So how can I have multiple methods  and display all on 1 window at the same time. I believe I could put it all in 1 method but this will get very long. Although not now, but I will have lots of methods all for putting their own unique thing on the window. Please see my current code below:

```
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GUI extends JPanel
{
/**
 * Creation of variables used throughout the GUI Class. 
 */ 
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private int lookReplyX = 5;
private int lookReplyY = 5;


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    GUI g = new GUI();

    g.create();
}

private void create()
{
    JFrame screen = new JFrame("Dungeon of Doom");
    screen.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //set size to full screen. 
    screen.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);   

    screen.setVisible(true);

    //Add all JPanes to screen
    screen.getContentPane().add(lookReplyGUI());
    screen.getContentPane().add(titlePanel());
}

private JPanel lookReplyGUI()
{
    JPanel lookReplyGUIPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    for(int y = lookReplyY; y>0; y--)
    {
        for(int x = lookReplyX; x>0; x--)
        {
            JLabel lookx = new JLabel(" " + y + "" + x);
            c.gridwidth = 1;
            c.gridheight = 1;
            c.gridx = x+1;
            c.gridy = y+1;
            lookReplyGUIPanel.add(lookx, c);
        }
    }
    return lookReplyGUIPanel;
}

private JPanel titlePanel()
{
    JPanel titlePanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    JLabel title = new JLabel("DOD");
    titlePanel.add(title, c);
    c.gridwidth = 7;
    c.gridheight = 1;
    c.gridx = lookReplyX+2;
    c.gridy = 1;


    return titlePanel;
}

}
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main cause of your problem is the fact that `JFrame` uses a `BorderLayout` by default, which means that only one component may occupy any one of the five available positions at a time.

The default position is `CENTER`. By doing...

```
screen.getContentPane().add(lookReplyGUI());
screen.getContentPane().add(titlePanel());
```

The `lookRelyGUI` component is effective made invisible (it's size and position are set to 0x0).

Instead, try using a different layout manager...

```
JFrame screen = new JFrame("Dungeon of Doom");
screen.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 0));
screen.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

//set size to full screen. 
screen.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);   

//Add all JPanes to screen
screen.getContentPane().add(lookReplyGUI());
screen.getContentPane().add(titlePanel());

// Do this only when you're ready
screen.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add a jPanel to your variables used throughout the class.

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private int lookReplyX = 5;
private int lookReplyY = 5;
private jPanel allPanels = new jPanel;
```

Then put all your panels inside that one and display that one...

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your code you are using. The reason why you only see one panel is because the 2nd panel is covered by the first. In default you did not set the size. To fix this you add

```
    private JPanel lookReplyGUI()
        { ...
            JLabel lookx = new JLabel(" " + y + "" + x);
            c.gridwidth = 1;
            c.gridheight = 1;
            c.gridx = x+1;
            c.gridy = y+1;
            lookReplyGUIPanel.add(lookx, c);
            lookReplyGUIPanel.setSize(100,100); //this line for example
        }
    ...
```

and

```
private JPanel titlePanel(){
...
    JLabel title = new JLabel("DOD");
    titlePanel.add(title, c);
    titlePanel.setSize(25,50); //this line for example
...
```

Then you can adjuest the panel position like you did to set the size as well.

Comment: Assuming that the container that lookRelpyGUI is added to is using a layout manager, the no, setSize will have no effect